# Select all unique entries showing a minimum of n records in a time range

Tags: r, filter, range, subset

I have the following dataset (32000 entries) of water chemical compounds annual means organized by monitoring sites and sampling year, example as follow:

```
data= data.frame(Site_ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Year=c(1976, 1977, 1978, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2003, 2004, 2005), AnnualMean=c(1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.1, 2.6, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6, 1.9))
```

I would like to select only data from all monitoring sites that have at least n measurements between a year1 and year2 ? Typically I would like to select all data from monitoring sites that show 10 measurenents between 1990 and 2005. So far I tried without success:

```
data %>%
group_by(Site_ID) %>%
filter(n()>=n %in% between(Year, year1, year2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects all `Site_ID` groups which contain at least `parms['n']` observations between `parms['yr1']` and `parms['yr2']`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

parms <- c(n = 2, yr1 = 2000, yr2 = 2005)

df[, if(sum(Year %between% parms[c('yr1', 'yr2')]) >= parms['n']) .SD, 
   by = Site_ID]

#    Site_ID Year AnnualMean
# 1:       2 2004        2.1
# 2:       2 2005        2.6
# 3:       2 2006        3.1
# 4:       3 2003        2.7
# 5:       3 2004        2.6
# 6:       3 2005        1.9
```

Comment: This solution worked very well, thank you very much and apologies for the delay replying !

Answer (score 1):

This code in Base-R works on the sample data you've provided. you can change the number in `IDstoGet <- Site_IDs[CountBySite_IDs >= 3]` to only take Site_IDs that have more than whatever number of datapoints you'd like.

```
DataInRange <- data[(data$Year>=1990&data$Year<=2005),]
Site_IDs <- unique(DataInRange$Site_ID)
CountBySite_IDs <- sapply(Site_IDs, function(x) length(grep(x,DataInRange$Site_ID)))
IDstoGet <- Site_IDs[CountBySite_IDs >= 3]
DataToGetPosition <- unlist(lapply(IDstoGet, grep, DataInRange$Site_ID))

DataInRange[DataToGetPosition,]
```

output

```
> DataInRange[DataToGetPosition,]
  Site_ID Year AnnualMean
7       3 2003        2.7
8       3 2004        2.6
9       3 2005        1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your expected result, maybe you can have a try

```
data %>%
  group_by(Site_ID) %>%
  filter(between(Year,1990,2005)) %>%
  filter(Year, n()>=10)
```

An base R alternative is

```
subset(data,
       !!ave(ave(Year,
                 Site_ID,
                 FUN = function(x) x>=1990&x<=2005),
             Site_ID,
             FUN = function(x) sum(x)>2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Store a scalar that's values represent the number of observations 
# You would like to filter the data set for: n => numeric vector: 
n <- 10

# Append a site count vector to a subset of the original df: sites_counted_df => data.frame:
sites_counted_df <-
  within(data[which(data$Year >= 1980 & data$Year <= 2005), ],
         {
           count <- ave(Site_ID, Site_ID, FUN = length)
         }
  )

# Filter the data.frame to contain records for sites above "n":
# n_observation_sites => data.frame
n_observation_sites <- sites_counted_df[which(count > n),]
```

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Site_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  Year = c(1976, 1977, 1978, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2003, 2004, 2005),
  AnnualMean = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.1, 2.6, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6, 1.9)
)
```